# WSO2 Application server Security option

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to build an application with a WSO2 Application server and Identity server.

the soap server which is based on Axis2 Framework needs to have WS-Trust based Authentication. For learning, I'm following this blog http://www.vitharana.org/2015/01/how-ws-trust-sts-works-in-wso2-identity.html

At the 14th steps, I have to click on security but In latest WSO2 Application server I'm not able to find how to enable the Security feature.

I'm using 5.3.0 Version of Application Server

[image: WSO2 AS 5.3.0]

As you can see there is no link on Unsecured for HelloWorld Service.

I'm I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the WSO2 products based on carbon kernel 4.4.x doesn't contain QoS features. WSO2 AS 5.3.0 is based on kernel version 4.4.x and therefore it is not supported. You can use WSO2 Developer Studio in order to apply QoS features

Comment: Thank you, it resolved. Though I'm facing another issue while running Sample code.  I have created another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471342/axisfault-missing-wssesecurity-header-in-request Question for the same.